# Why do I get an warning message in my log that says my UINavigationController is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, nserror

I get this warning:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x137e1ff80> on <HomePageViewController: 0x137e0ae30> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I'm trying top modal from my HomePageViewController to my CreatePageViewController...just a simple segue.

HomePageViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)goToCreate:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"createModal" sender:self];
}
```

and I created a custom modal to CreatePageViewController with an identifier called "createModal", and I embedded CreatePageViewController in a UINavigationController.

Why do you think I get this warning..?

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with your storyboards, try to initiate from code:
Set to CreatePageViewController in storyboard "storyboard Id" and then use this code:

```
CreatePageViewController *CreateVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"*here storyboard id*"];
[self presentViewController:CreateVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If that's ok, then problem in UINavigation hierarchy.